# summing and multiplying the rows and putting them into two extra columns

Tags: matlab

i take an input matrix and add two more columns to it. i'll have the sums of the rows in the first extra column and the product of the rows in the second extra column.
but an unexpected error is stopping me...please help.thanks

```
clc;
clear all;

prompt = ' enter row ';

row = input( prompt );

prompt = ' enter column ';

column = input( prompt );

z = zeros( row, column );

prompt = 'enter matrix';

z = input( '' );

display( z );

z1= zeros( row, column + 2 );

for r = 1:row

       for c = 1:column
        z1( r,c ) = z( r,c );
    end
end

display( z1 );

for s = 1:row

      z1( s,column + 1 ) = sum( z,2 );
      z1( s,column + 2 ) = prod( z,2 );
end

display( z1 );
```

Answer (score 0):

You're modifying `z`

`z = zeros( row, column );`

then doing

`z = input( prompt );`

Take some different variable name

Also, last loop logic is incorrect

Use something like this:

`z=[z sum(z,2) prod(z,2)]`

Example :

```
>> z=magic(3)

z =

     8     1     6
     3     5     7
     4     9     2

>> z=[z sum(z,2) prod(z,2)]

z =

     8     1     6    15    48
     3     5     7    15   105
     4     9     2    15    72
```

Comment: @istiak.inam sorry for so many edited, i misread your question, see now

Comment: @istiak.inam well `z1( s,column + 1 ) ` and `z1( s,column + 2 )` are matrix individual elements and you're trying to assign a `rx1`  obtained from `sum` and `prod` matrix to it, that too in a loop